# Remove Row with Button Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, so I need to delete the `row/div onclick` of button.
So far I have this:

```
<h2>Header 3</h2>

    <div id="results3" class="results">
        <h1>Results 3</h1>
        <div id="1">Item 1 <button type="button" onclick="remove()">Remove</button></div>
        <div id="2">Item 2 <button type="button" onclick="remove()">Remove</button></div>
        <div id="3">Item 3 <button type="button" onclick="remove()">Remove</button></div>
        <div id="4">Item 4 <button type="button" onclick="remove()">Remove</button></div>
    </div>
```

As you can see this is all written into my html, the `onclick="remove()"` only removes the button, not the entire row this is my problem.

As having all of this in the html is bad practice I would also like to know how I could put assign the event handler to the button just in my javascript.

JS Script:

```
function() {

    var results = document.getElementById('results3');
    var buttons = results.getElementsByTagName('button')
}
```

Comment: where's your script..?

Comment: I don't have any functional script yet I have added this above now.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and move away from inline event binding (`onclick="...`) and use centralised event binding from within your script.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance.
The jQuery solution was ideal for this situation, however all answers were great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery, I assume a jQuery-solution is OK with you:

Add a `class="remove"` to your buttons, and use this javascript.

```
$(function() {
    $('button.remove').click(function() {
         $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
});
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TgBKM/

Comment: or `$(".results div button").click();` would work with the existing structure

Comment: It does indeed, but I prefer to be more specific in selectors like those as it is less prone to errors (when further developping the page).

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<div id="1">Item 1 
    <button type="button" onclick="remove(this)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
 function remove(removeMe)
  {
      $(removeMe).remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" onclick="remove(this)">Remove</button>
```

*Javascript*

```
var remove = function(btn){
    btn.parentNode.style.display="none";
    //Remove the div
    //var div =  btn.parentNode;
    //div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/6267J/)